# Accessing French dictionaries on Cloud Reader

Tags: kindle-cloud-reader

How can I add French Dictionaries to my Cloud Reader? 
I live in Canada.  Canada is a bilingual country, and I am bilingual, so I read books in both French and English.  But Cloud Reader only offers me dictionaries for US and UK English -- and Spanish!

Answer (score 1):

According to [André Klein](https://learnoutlive.com/german-english-dictionary-kindle-cloud-reader/) September 27, 2015

> trying to get Kindle PC to accept custom dictionaries ultimately proved futile

but he does go on to mention:

> binarycrafts from Romania have found a way to circumvent Kindle Cloud reader’s blocking of text copying by use of a simple bookmarklet.

The code for this is copied below:

```
javascript:(function(){var w=null;var kDoc=null;var kObj=null;if(typeof window.KindleReaderContextMenu!=='undefined'){w=window;}else if(window.length){for(var i=0;i<window.length;i++){if(typeof window[i].KindleReaderContextMenu!=='undefined'){w=window[i];break;}}}
if(typeof w==='object'){kObj=w.KindleReaderContextMenu;kDoc=w.document;if(typeof kObj.ACRExtensions==='undefined'){kObj.ACRExtensions=true;var oldMethod=kObj.show;kObj.show=function(){var res=oldMethod.apply(kObj,arguments);var txtDoc=null;var r=null;if(typeof(arguments[3])!=='undefined'&&typeof(arguments[3]['start'])!=='undefined'){var sId=arguments[3]['start'];var eId=arguments[3]['end'];$('iframe',kDoc).each(function(j,textIframe){var textIFrameDoc=$(textIframe).contents().get(0);if($('#'+sId,textIFrameDoc).get(0)){txtDoc=textIFrameDoc;return false;}});if(txtDoc){r=txtDoc.createRange();r.setStartBefore($('#'+sId,txtDoc).get(0));r.setEndAfter($('#'+eId,txtDoc).get(0));}}
$('#ACRExtensions_copyB_sep',kDoc).remove();$('#ACRExtensions_copyB',kDoc).remove();$('#ACRExtensions_copyC',kDoc).remove();var styles=$('<style>.spinner, .dictionary.i18n.expanded {display:none !important;} div#kindleReader_menu_contextMenu { max-height: 35px;}</style>');var sepEl=$('<div id="ACRExtensions_copyB_sep" class="kindle_menu_separator"></div>');var copyB=$('<div id="ACRExtensions_copyB" class="kindle_menu_button button_enabled ui-corner-left">dict.cc</div>');var copyC=$('<div id="ACRExtensions_copyC" class="kindle_menu_button button_enabled ui-corner-left">Google</div>');$('#kindle_menu_border',kDoc).append(sepEl).append(copyB).append(sepEl).append(copyC).append(styles);setTimeout(function(){sepEl.show();copyB.removeClass('button_hidden');copyC.removeClass('button_hidden');},1);$('#ACRExtensions_copyB',kDoc).click(function(evt){if(r){var newW=window.open('http://pocket.dict.cc/?s='+ r,'dict.cc',"height=400,width=448,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0");}});$('#ACRExtensions_copyC',kDoc).click(function(evt){if(r){var newW=window.open('https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#auto/en/'+ r,'Google Translate',"height=400,width=776,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0");}});return res;};alert('Kindle Translator Extension is now active.');}else{alert('Kindle Translator Extension is already active.');}}else{alert('Error: Kindle Translator Extension is not active. The Amazon Cloud Reader window could not be found.');}})();
```

but the first link, while still live, has more details and is a better source.